# Will guid generation logic ever generate 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?

Tags: random, null, guid, reserved-words

I have run into a scenario where a customer may have a nullable guid for me to compare to in my database. I *could go ahead* and rewrite my call stack to make the object nullable, but I also don't want to do that. I'm considering just doing a null check at the data ingestion point and coalescing to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, but am not sure if that's "safe" as I'm not sure if a guid generator could actually generate that guid randomly

(yes, I know that I could pick any random guid and the odds of a guid generator picking it are stupidly low, but I'm really more curious if the 0-value guid is reserved)

Comment: If this is C# or .NET you should tag this question as such.  In that case, you can look at the .NET source code or documentation to see what it does.

Comment: It appears at least 500 people (the max possible on this site) have suggested edits to this question and @Sidney hasn't come back to resolve this. I am guessing from his "database" comment he intended this as a SQL question. However imo this is actually a language-agnostic question?

Comment: @AndrewD That's interesting -- I (believe) I normally get a notification when there is a suggested edit. I also don't see that there is any indication the post has ever been edited. As this was a year ago I don't really remember what I was asking this about, but think I would notice about two edit requests per day. Can you speak to the content of the suggested edits? Maybe there's a bug in the notification system.

Comment: @Sidney I say "appears" because when I tried to edit your question and propose a change I got a "too many pending edits" error - researching it I found https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338921/too-many-pending-edits ?! I see that today I can edit your question .. weird

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR it is safe to use `COALESCE(MyGUID, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')`.

I did some research and, as best I can determine, it IS theoretically possible to generate this value since it is obtained by all the bits being set to `0`.

However, according to [RFC4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122) the way its constructed means this will never happen (some bits are added to help with the uniqueness).
The RFC also specifically refers to the "NIL GUID", though it doesn't mention whether this is reserved or whether it will ever be hit.

Even if the [total number of possible GUIDs](https://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2007/07/23/guid-how-many-combinations-are-there/) were possible, this is 2^212.
So the chances of getting that particular value is 1 in 5,316,911,983,139,663,491,615,228,241,121,400,000 !

For comparison the chances of a collision are 1 in 1,000,000,000.
And while the probability that a UUID collision will occur is not zero, it is [generally considered so close to zero as to be negligible](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#uuid).

Lastly many languages use the value as a *nil GUID* i.e. it is reserved e.g. C#'s `Guid.Empty`.

So I surmise that it is safe to use in a coalesce in any language as long as you are using generated GUIDs (i.e. you don't have a someone or something that could manually set / pass in / insert a *nil GUID* value).